# store array in the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have three arrays example: $array1,$array2,$array3.

I want to insert the array2 and array3 in two different columns in the same table.
can i do that?

here is the code below that i am trying but it does not work for me i am doing in codeigniter:

- controller:

  ```
   $athletes_id = $this->input->post('athletes'); // array 1
   $fields_id = $this->input->post('fields_id');  // array 2
   $athlete_score = $this->input->post('athlete_score');  // array 3


   $id = array();
   foreach($athlete_score as $row){
   $additional_data = array(
   'test_reports_id' => $test_report_id,
   'score' => $row,
   );
   $id[] = $this->test_model->save_test_reports_details($additional_data);
   }
   for($j=0;$j<count($fields_id);$j++){
   $data2 = array('fields_id' => $fields_id[$j]);
   $this->test_model->update_test_reports_details($id,$data2);
   }
  ```
- Model :

  ```
     public function update_test_reports_details($id,$data2){
     $this->db->where_in('id',$id);
     $this->db->update('test_reports_details',$data2);
     }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Just serialize the arrays.

```
$data2 = serialize($array2); // or whatever array you want to store
```

Then to retrieve with unserialize

```
$array2 = unserialize($data2);//or the row index
```

Answer (score 0):

To store array in database you have to serialize it.

Try :

```
public function update_test_reports_details($id,$data2){
$this->db->where_in('id',$id);
$this->db->update('test_reports_details',serialize($data2));
}
```

To unserialize it when you get it from the database you have to use unserialize()

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize as suggested in other answers, however I personally prefer to json_encode the array.

```
$data = json_encode($array);
```

And when you are reading in the model you should decode the data:

```
$array = json_decode($data, true); // set second argument to true to get an associative array
```

Using JSON has the advantage of better readability while still in the DB. This might not seem like much, but it can really help in some cases.

Comment: During `json_decode` please a true parameter to get the array in its original format. ie `$array = json_decode($data,true);`